# finding if a point lies within a set distance from a line, knowing only points along the line

Tags: math, geolocation, geometry

I need to ensure that a point is no more than x distance from a line derived from multiple other points.

If I plot lat/long points every 3 miles, I can infer a 'line' to travel. I want to make sure that 'potential' destinations are no more than 1 mile from that line. (the "multiple" points wont always be the same from instance to instance, BUT will be consistent per instance, and the "acceptable" distance from the line can vary per instance).

The tricky part is I have points, not a line...(the line is implied). Things work out "ok" if my "acceptable distance" is greater then my distance between the multiple points. however... If, say, my multiples are 2.5 apart, and I say a distance of 1 is acceptable for any point of interest. Then there are points between the two original points, that lie along the line but I can figure easily.

So I though since I have ONE measurement, I know the length of a line (on x axis, the distance between 2 of the multiple points..). I could treat that as one of two equal sides of a triangle and figure the hypotenuse.

```
d = distance between (each, multiple) points.
a = ( d/2 )
b = ( d/2 )
c = sq root of ( a^2 + b^2 )
```

C is going to be slightly larger then my initial "acceptable distance", so I'll use that.

Is there an better way to figure???

thx

Lets see if I can illustrate

```
point A                             point B
   O----------------------------------O

distance form point A to point B is 5 miles...


Now...
 point A                             point B
   O----------------------------------O

               point C
                    O
```

Question: is point C inside of 1 mile from the line that connects point A and B?????

How does one express this with math? such that the distance between points can be expressed as a variable.

This is a mapping problem, points of interest close to a 'road' or 'path' that has sample points as Lat/long the point of interest also has a lat/long.

If I use a triangle or intersecting circles, I end up with peaks or humps that are well outside of my 'acceptable distance off path', just to accommodate the space between my samples.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the distance from a line which is defined by two points using the formula here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

[image: formula]

Answer (score 0):

A perpendicular line segment will be your friend in this problem. Find a line segment perpendicular to AB which contains point C.
The intersection of the line segments would be point D.
Get the distance of segment CD and you have your answer.